# Is there anyway to log in the case history workflow rules triggering?

Tags: workflow, time-dependent-workflow

Whenever a workflow rule triggers, we want to log it in the case history. Is there anyway to log that natively? I think we could do it by adding a field update to the workflow rule which adds the name of the workflow rule to an invisible field, then track that field in the field history, but my only concern is that for time-based rules, it will effectively double the amount of workflows we have running at any given point.

Comment: time-based workflow always updates the case history, then why are you adding the field tracking for workflow update?

Comment: the way it updates the cases are vague, i.e. it will say the person who triggered the rule updated the case. it also does not indicate which rule has fired

Comment: there is an idea around that, you vote for that idea

Comment: do you know where that idea is? thanks